# My text and url uploaded via intent are too long for twitter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, twitter, share

I develop app for android.
I need send text and link via intent to twitter, but text and link are too long. In web version links will always be shortened, but on app not. Is possible send this message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765747/is-it-possible-to-shorten-url-from-twitter-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use google api shorturl before sending a link or text .. this is my app code . manage with your requirements. hope it will give you  an idea.

**shortUrl method**

```
public static String shortUrl(String data) {
            String shortUrl = "";
            String serverResponse = "";
            try {
                // Set connection timeout to 5 secs and socket timeout to 10 secs
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                int timeoutConnection = 5000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                        timeoutConnection);
                int timeoutSocket = 10000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("longUrl", data);
                request.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                HttpResponse response = hc.execute(request);

                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    serverResponse = out.toString();
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

                if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(serverResponse)) {
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
                    if (data != null) {
                        Constants.shortUrl = shortUrl = data.getString("id");
                    }
                } else {
                    shortUrl = shortUrl = data;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                shortUrl = shortUrl = data;
            }
            return shortUrl;
    }
```

**tweeet text**

```
String tweetMessage = "";
    String shortUrl = shortUrl(String somedata);
    if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(shareText)){
        int len = shareText.length();
        int mlen = 140-(shortUrl.length()+8);
        int tlen = Math.min(len, mlen);
        String separator = " ... ";
        if(tlen!=mlen)
        {
            separator = " - ";
        }
        tweetMessage = shareText.substring(0, tlen)+separator+shortUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        tweetMessage = "Checkout ... "+shortUrl;
    }


        try {


        //send a tweet here... 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```